# Easiest way to call parent constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, extending-classes

I am using an entity framework with a public  `ParentClass` where the `function` does a lot of important things by searching configurations and DataBase entries and cannot edit this code as it is from a third-party. However I want to add extra “search” on white-listed information the `function` in the `ParentClass` can’t access.

The code below is a mock-up of what’s going on. I’m just wondering, is there a better way of extending the `ParentClass` and getting access to it’s `function`

```
public ParentClass : ClassInterface
{
    foo bar;
    public Parent(foo _bar) 
    {
        this.bar = _bar
    }

    function(int) 
    {
        // do things with this.bar
    }
}

public ChildClass : ParentClass, ClassInterface 
{
    public ChildClass(foo _bar) : base(_bar) { }


    public virtual function(int) 
    {
        bool x = base.function(int)
        if (!x) 
        {
            ... stuff
        }

        ... otherstuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is more suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is the `base.function` public, or really private? This doesn't really "extend" the parent class, and I'm sure you are getting a compiler warning about hiding base class methods. `virtual` doesn't override or hide the base class method, so the only way the `ChildClass.function` gets called is if the method using the `ChildClass` knows its a `ChildClass`, aka, if `DoSomething(ParentClass pc)` is passed a child class, it will call the `ParentClass.function`, not the `ChildClass.function` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

calling the `base.function()` is the pedantically right thing to do. So your code is doing the correct thing. That being said, the moment you think you need something like this, you should be considering a more composition-based approach.